# baudrate usart5 raspberry pi 4

Tags: pi-4, uart

I need to connect raspberry pi 4 to a microprocessor, and I am using uart5 (dtoverlay=uart5 at the end of config.txt). What I need is to change the baudrate to 4800, because this is the baudrate I use in the microprocessor. What is the command I need to use in the Raspberry and how this change could be permanent?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You will be using a software driver or software library to talk to the UART.

When you "open" the UART with that software you will specify the baud rate.  The method used depends on the driver/library you choose to use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have Cutecom installed in the Raspberry. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I have never heard of cutecom.  If it talks to serial links it will have the ability to set the baud rate.

Comment: In cutecom, you can open ttyAMA1, for example, and choose any bps from a list, but I dont think this app changes anything in the usart, just takes and gives data at the choosen speed. Have you heard about minicom? is that one ok. Thanks